# Merging a lot of data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge multiple data frames in a list simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list-simultaneously)

example `data.frames`:

```
 df1 = data.frame(id=c('1','73','2','10','43'),v1=c(1,2,3,4,5)) <br>
 df2 = data.frame(id=c('7','23','57','2','62','96'),v2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) <br>
 df3 = data.frame(id=c('23','62'),v3=c(1,2)) <br>
```

Note: `id` is unique for each data.frame. I want the resulting matrix to look like

```
1      1 NA NA 
2      3  4 NA 
7      NA 1 NA 
10     4 NA NA 
23     NA 2  1 
43     5 NA NA 
57     NA 3 NA 
62     NA 5  2 
73     2 NA NA 
96     NA 6 NA
```

In this case, I only show 3 datasets, I actually have at least 22 of them so at the end I want a matrix of nx(22+1) where n is the number of ids for all 22 datasets.

Given 2 datasets, I need to get their `ids` in the first column and 2nd and 3rd columns are filled with the values, if there is no value exists, then input `NA` instead.

Comment: This is not a solution but in addition to what is stated by @Matthew Plourde. You can build list of data.frames: df_list <- lapply(paste0("df",1:22), as.name).

Comment: Even though this thread may be duplicate of another, but both questions and answers are presented in a more readable way.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Put them into a `list` and use `merge` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
#    id v1 v2 v3
# 1   1  1 NA NA
# 2  10  4 NA NA
# 3   2  3  4 NA
# 4  43  5 NA NA
# 5  73  2 NA NA
# 6  23 NA  2  1
# 7  57 NA  3 NA
# 8  62 NA  5  2
# 9   7 NA  1 NA
# 10 96 NA  6 NA
```

You can also use this more concise version:

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

Comment: +1 for `Reduce`.  For this simple example, this is equivalent to `merge(merge(df1, df2, by='id', all=T), df3, by='id', all=T)`.  Clearly a loop could be used, iterating through the data frames -- but that's exactly what `Reduce` does.

Comment: I'm thankful `Reduce` is in the language, but I really wish it were more like the `*apply` functions, letting you give it additional arguments for the functional supplied. I hate that I have to embed a function definition just to use `merge` with `all=TRUE`.

Comment: `merge_recurse` and `merge_all` from the (older) reshape package are a decent guide for how to build something that does this for you in a more convenient form.

Comment: Can I ask how to modify the function if we would have to account for different `ids` across those data frames?

Comment: I think it would be easiest to standardize the id column names. The hack to handle this with `Reduce` would get kind of obscure.

Comment: I tried this method and it is really slow with 500 lists each with 125 rows. Are there any other fast methods

Comment: @PollaA.Fattah take a look at the join functions in the dplyr package

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Thank you for your reply it turns out my problem was simpler than what I thought of and I used rbind eventually.

Comment: It was fast (immediate) with 8 data frames with ~3000 rows each

Comment: I am using merge and reduce, but geeting the following error:  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.5 Gb, please help

Comment: @gauravkumar Welcome to the world of big data. You'll want to check out the CRAN task view on high-performance computing (https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), especially the section called "Large memory and out-of-memory data"

Comment: How to handle if one of tables is null? It affects the results but should be automatically excluded

Comment: @Peter.k just filter first

Comment: I faced a warning when `by = 0` saying the "Row.name" is duplicated. It turned out that the merge function does something stupid when trying to merge based on row.names. The solution I found is to move the row.names into a column and use that to merge. Hopefully this is useful to those who are desperately looking for an answer about the warning and misbehave of `merge`.

Comment: @MehradMahmoudian how did you do that?

Comment: @Luis basically just create a new column for each dataframe/matrix and fill it with the rownames (e.g `df$rownames <- row.names(df)`) and then while merging use `by = "rownames"`.

Comment: I wonder how to use the `suffixes` argument from `merge.data.table` when multiple dataframes have columns with the same name, not counting the matching column.