# Using Reduce to merge multiple data frames with passing arguments and without defining function outside the Reduce (syntax)

Tags: r, function, merge, dataframe

I've a a list with a number of data set that corresponds to the object generated below:

```
data("AirPassengers"); data("mtcars")
lstDta <- list(dtaCars1 = mtcars, dtaCars2 = mtcars,
               dtaCars3 = mtcars, dtaOtherStuff = AirPassengers)
```

I would like to merge the *cars* data sets on *row.names*

## Results

The results should correspond to the data frame:

```
res <- merge(
    x = merge(x = lstDta$dtaCars1, y = lstDta$dtaCars2, by = "row.names"),
    y = lstDta$dtaCars3, by.y = "row.names",
    by.x = "Row.names")
```

where the columns are joined using `row.names` *(ideally, I would drop the `Row.names` variable but this doesn't bother me)*:

```
> dim(res)
[1] 32 34
```

## Problem

I want to achieve the same results making use of `Reduce`, in particular I am interested in:

- Merging the data frames on the `row.names`
- Filtering the list. For example, I want to merge the *cars* data only and ignore the *other* data set

### Additional requirements

[Very useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17171655/1655567) suggests defining a function outside reduce, on the lines of the code:

> ```
> merge.all <- function(x, y) {
>     merge(x, y, all=TRUE, by="Sample")
> }
>
> output <- Reduce(merge.all, DataList)
> ```

I would like to avoid defining the function outside the `Reduce` syntax.

### Attempt

As shown in the attempt below, I would like to cram everything inside the `Reduce`:

```
dtaMrgd <- Reduce(f = function(x,y) {merge(x,y, by = "row.names")},
              lapply(lstDta[grepl("Cars", names(lstDta)) == TRUE]))
```

so the `Reduce` does two things:

1. Filters the passed list using string according to matching names
2. Uses the filtered object to apply merge function with the desired characteristics

*Needles to say, the code above fails.*

---

## Notes

*I'm specifically interested in a solution that would be of format **`res <- Reduce( ... )`**. I'm not interested in creating some additional objects/functions outside the `Reduce()`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is one way to achieve what you want:

```
res2 <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
  data.frame(merge(x, y, by = 0), row.names = row.names(x))[,-1]
}, lstDta[grep("Cars", names(lstDta))])

dim(res2)
#[1] 32 33

names(res2)
#[1] "mpg.x"  "cyl.x"  "disp.x" "hp.x"   "drat.x" "wt.x"   "qsec.x" "vs.x"   "am.x"   "gear.x" "carb.x"
#[12] "mpg.y"  "cyl.y"  "disp.y" "hp.y"   "drat.y" "wt.y"   "qsec.y" "vs.y"   "am.y"   "gear.y" "carb.y"
#[23] "mpg"    "cyl"    "disp"   "hp"     "drat"   "wt"     "qsec"   "vs"     "am"     "gear"   "carb"
```

---

- To filter the input list, I'm using `lstDta[grep("Cars", names(lstDta))]`
- I drop the first column of each merged result (`Row.names`) with `[,-1]`
- You can use `by = 0` as a synonym for `row.names` to avoid any problems trying to merge on `Row.names` and `row.names`
- Without the explicit `data.frame(..., row.names = row.names(x))`, merge will drop the original `mtcars` row names and replace them with the default `1:nrow(x)`. This would be problematic for ensuing merge calls.

---

From the helpfile `?merge`,

> Columns to merge on can be specified by name, number or by a logical
>   vector: the name "row.names" or the number 0 specifies the row names.
>   If specified by name it must correspond uniquely to a named column in
>   the input.

Comment: It appears to be working like a charm, could you please explain why you did: `data.frame(merge(x, y, by = 0)`?