# How to create a function for multiple columns of a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to create a function for making tables using columns of data frame:

```
Freq_table=function(x){
   x<-factor(x)
   T<-table(STI_IPD$Q19_1,x,exclude = NULL)

   T<- data.frame(T)
   library(reshape2)
   T_x<-dcast(T, Var1~Var2)
   T_x<-T_x%>%select(-starts_with("NA"),-ends_with("NA"))

}
```

here STI_IPD is my Dataframe, and x should be any column which I'm using to create tables with another column Q19_1

This is throwing error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Var2' not found

```
   Data.frame(T) output is:

                Var1           Var2 Freq
1              Consumer Goods    1    1
2               Life Sciences    1    0
3                   Chemicals    1    0
4         Other Manufacturing    1    0
5                   High Tech    1    0
6                      Energy    1    0
7             Mining & Metals    1    0
8          Retail & Wholesale    1    0
9  Banking/Financial Services    1    0
10      Insurance/Reinsurance    1    0
11   Services (Non-Financial)    1    0
12                  Logistics    1    0
13    Other Non-Manufacturing    1    0
14             Consumer Goods <NA>    1
15              Life Sciences <NA>    1
16                  Chemicals <NA>    1
17        Other Manufacturing <NA>    4
18                  High Tech <NA>    1
19                     Energy <NA>    5
20            Mining & Metals <NA>    0
21         Retail & Wholesale <NA>    1
22 Banking/Financial Services <NA>    5
23      Insurance/Reinsurance <NA>    3
24   Services (Non-Financial) <NA>    5
25                  Logistics <NA>    2
26    Other Non-Manufacturing <NA>    3
```

output of dput(head(STI_IPD, 30)) is below:

```
structure(list(Q18_1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Q19_1 = structure(c(9L, 13L, 1L, 9L, 
2L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 
3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 10L), .Label = c("Consumer Goods", 
"Life Sciences", "Chemicals", "Other Manufacturing", "High Tech", 
"Energy", "Mining & Metals", "Retail & Wholesale", "Banking/Financial Services", 
"Insurance/Reinsurance", "Services (Non-Financial)", "Logistics", 
"Other Non-Manufacturing"), class = "factor"), Q46_21_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_21_5 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_21_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_21_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_22_4 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), Q46_22_5 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_22_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_22_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_23_4 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), Q46_23_5 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Q46_23_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Q46_23_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), Q46_24_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_24_5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_24_6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_24_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_25_4 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_25_5 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_25_6 = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_25_7 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_26_4 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_26_5 = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_26_6 = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_26_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_27_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_27_5 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_27_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_27_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_28_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), Q46_28_5 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), Q46_28_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), Q46_28_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), Q46_29_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_29_5 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_29_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_29_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_30_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_30_5 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_30_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_30_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_31_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_31_5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_31_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_31_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_32_4 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_32_5 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_32_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_32_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Q46_33_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_33_5 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_33_6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_33_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_34_4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_34_5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_34_6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q46_34_7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Q18_1", 
"Q19_1", "Q46_21_4", "Q46_21_5", "Q46_21_6", "Q46_21_7", "Q46_22_4", 
"Q46_22_5", "Q46_22_6", "Q46_22_7", "Q46_23_4", "Q46_23_5", "Q46_23_6", 
"Q46_23_7", "Q46_24_4", "Q46_24_5", "Q46_24_6", "Q46_24_7", "Q46_25_4", 
"Q46_25_5", "Q46_25_6", "Q46_25_7", "Q46_26_4", "Q46_26_5", "Q46_26_6", 
"Q46_26_7", "Q46_27_4", "Q46_27_5", "Q46_27_6", "Q46_27_7", "Q46_28_4", 
"Q46_28_5", "Q46_28_6", "Q46_28_7", "Q46_29_4", "Q46_29_5", "Q46_29_6", 
"Q46_29_7", "Q46_30_4", "Q46_30_5", "Q46_30_6", "Q46_30_7", "Q46_31_4", 
"Q46_31_5", "Q46_31_6", "Q46_31_7", "Q46_32_4", "Q46_32_5", "Q46_32_6", 
"Q46_32_7", "Q46_33_4", "Q46_33_5", "Q46_33_6", "Q46_33_7", "Q46_34_4", 
"Q46_34_5", "Q46_34_6", "Q46_34_7"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000090788>)
```

Comment: I have 13 columns for which I am repeating the same activity:

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(STI_IPD, 30))` in your question? In the mean time, what are the names of the columns of `data.frame(T)`?

Comment: Hi, I have added the data frame gimpse and the Data.frame(T)output.Thanks

Comment: Look, I have asked for the output of `dput(...)` because with it we can simply copy&paste into an R session, it will recreate your data *exactly* as you have it. Thanks for the edit but it's much better to post what I've asked for. Also, how do you call your function? What do you pass as its argument `x`?

Comment: Hi, I have added dput(head(STI_IPD, 30)) , This function has error. I want column names to be passed as x . I am doing this to generate crosstabs/freq tables of columns with another fix column Q19_1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following.

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

Freq_table <- function(x){
    dat <- data.frame(Q19_1 = STI_IPD$Q19_1, STI_IPD[[x]])
    names(dat)[2] <- x
    m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "Q19_1")
    result <- tryCatch(dcast(m, Q19_1 ~ variable), error = function(e) message(e))
    result <- result %>% select(-starts_with("NA"),-ends_with("NA"))
    result
}

Freq_table("Q46_22_5")
Freq_table("Q46_34_4")
```

Note that you pass to the function the *names* of the columns you want, not the columns themselves.

**EDIT.**
To answer to a request of the OP in a comment, the following code will apply the function above to all but the two first columns of the input dataframe `STI_IPD` and then `merge` all the results into one df. The `Reduce/merge`code is the answer by Hong Ooi to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171426/r-merge-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-missing-values-by-row).

```
lst <- lapply(names(STI_IPD[-(1:2)]), Freq_table)
lst <- lst[!sapply(lst, is.null)]

merge.all <- function(x, y) {
    merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = "Q19_1")
}

output <- Reduce(merge.all, lst)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem. I have one more question. I am making tables using 13 columns with this function and in a later stage I want to join these tables by Q19_1. But for one table there is only one column. So how should I join all tables where this column is taken all o or Na?

Comment: @SandhyaGhildiyal Maybe with `?merge`, it's difficult to tell without seeing the result data.

Comment: Hi @Rui Barradas, This function giving wrong result, ay be its counting NAs also, that's what I figured out after comparison

Comment: if we use dcast(m, Q19_1 ~ value), we will a separate column for NA.

Comment: @SandhyaGhildiyal See my edit. Maybe it is what you want.

Comment: Hi, this edited solution is also giving the same output, and NAs are not saparated. Actually problem is for Q46_34_4. this column has all NA counts. Do know how to handle this function

Comment: See this is what I want Freq_table <- function(x){
  dat <- data.frame(Q19_1 = Q46_exc$Q19_1, Q46_exc[[x]])
  names(dat)[2] <- x
  m <- melt(dat)
  T<-tryCatch(dcast(m, Q19_1 ~ value),error = function(e) message(e))
  T<-T%>%select(-starts_with("NA"),-ends_with("NA"))
  T
}, but this can not handle Q46_34_4

Comment: @SandhyaGhildiyal Just edited the code again. Now it handles `Q46_34_4`.

Comment: Hi, dcast(m, Q19_1 ~ variable) is not giving right answer. dcast(m, Q19_1 ~ value) is giving right output. and finally this one is working: newfreq <- function(x){
  STI_IPD[[x]]<-factor(STI_IPD[[x]])
  T<-table(STI_IPD$Q19_1,STI_IPD[[x]],exclude = NULL)
  dat <- data.frame(T)
  library(reshape2)
  T1<-dcast(dat, Var1~Var2)
  T1<-T1%>%select(-starts_with("NA"),-ends_with("NA"))
  names(T1)<-c("Industry",paste("new",x,sep = "_"))
  T1
}