# How to find matches across many large data.frames/data.tables from one source file?

Tags: r, database, merge, data.table, lapply

I am a slightly novice R user, and I am wondering how to automate finding matching rows (e.g., inner join merge), from one "master" data.table across multiple, large (meaning ~8 GB files) data.tables, and to take those matches and place them in one final table.

The "master" data.table has two columns and looks like this:

```
pid    pkid
123    8975A
456    9683
```

While the multiple, larger data.tables look like this:

```
pid    pkid   pha
123    8975A  3
456    9683   2
789    1253   3
```

I have my code set up to read all of the special delimited files from one directory, set the key for the data.table merge, and  to make names from the files:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.txt$", "", temp))), 
         fread,sep="|",setkey(packageid,patientid)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Where I'm stuck is how to automate the numerous (40 something?) merges from the one "master" data.table and to dump all of the matches from the many merges into a separate data.table. Basically, I want all the cases in the larger data.tables that have matching `pid` and `pkid` to the "master" to get the corresponding `pha`.

The only way that I've come up with is tragically manual, and will take a long time to write out, and is undoubtedly highly inefficient.

```
res1<-data.table::merge(master,dt1)
res2<-data.table::merge(master,dt2)
l=list(res1,res2)
final<-rbindlist(l)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), list(master, dt1, dt2..))`?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with list2env there, but I would rbindlist with an idcol instead, and then merge master on the result.

Comment: Sumedh - this method won't take the "pha" column that I wanted. Frank - could you explain some more?

Comment: @heesemonster, I don't see why not. You should probably include the `all` set of arguments in `merge`, but that still shouldn't be the reason why `pha` is not in the merged dataframe. FYI, here are the relevant links: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/r-merging-a-lot-of-data-frames) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Comment: After your `lapply`, you have a list of tables. Instead of using list2env, keep it as a list; call rbindlist on it so you have a single table, using the `idcol` argument to keep track of the source; then just merge master with this large table.

Comment: Frank & Sumedh: I was able to get the "pha" column and it all works great now. Thanks so much!!