# combine files using join_all

Tags: r, join, plyr

I am trying to join files using the following command:

```
join_all(dfs = datalist,by = "V1",type="left",match="all")
```

The problem is that when I use `type="full"` it does not combine the files, but if I use `type="left"` it works. However, I need the fll data set.

Any ideas why or suggestions on another method?

Comment: Please include the names of any packages you are using. `join_all` is not a base R function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide some reproducible code and the desired output.

It seems you are using the `join_all` function from the plyr package.

Another approach is to leverage the `Reduce` function in base R.

Check out this related SO post.

[R: merging a lot of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/r-merging-a-lot-of-data-frames)