# How to properly merge data-frames with a loop

Tags: r, merge

If I want to avoid a for loop (and use lapply or do.call instead), how can I merge data frames like below (cbind is not really an option in my case).
I have a given "base" data frame and a function that creates several data frames to add.

```
set.seed(1)

# creates example data frames
newCol <- function(x) {
  add_df <-data.frame("nr" = 1:5, runif(1))
  colnames(add_df)[2] <- x
  return(add_df)
}

# for-version - gives wanted result, but with for
df_base <- newCol("A")
for (x in x_vec) {
  df_base <- merge(df_base, newCol(x), on = "nr")
}
print(df_base)

# cbind - creates unnecessary "nr"-columns
df_base <- newCol("A")
do.call(cbind, lapply(x_vec, newCol))

# want: solution with merge (!) and lapply/do.call
```

Thx & kind regards

Comment: Use the `Reduce` route i.e. `Reduce(function(...) merge(...,  by = "nr"), lapply(x_vec, newCol))`  BTW, in `merge`, the argument is `by`.  May be it is a mixing of `data.table` join syntax

Comment: Thanks. Found the right link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames