# R - Merge list of three dataframes into single dataframe with ID in first column, next three columns show values

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's my list of data frames:

```
[[1]]
ID   Value
A   1
B   1
C   1

[[2]]
ID   Value
A   1
D   1
E   1

[[3]]
ID   Value
B   1
C   1
```

I'm after a single data frame with unique (non-redundant) IDs in the left hand column, replicates in columns, and NULL values as 0:

```
ID   [1]Value   [2]Value   [3]Value  
A    1          1          0
B    1          0          1
C    1          0          1
D    0          1          0
E    0          1          0
```

I've tried:

`Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=ID), datahere)`

This provides a single list but without regards to where the original values come from, and duplicate IDs are repeated in new rows.

```
rbindlist(datahere, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol="Replicate")
```

This provides a single list with the [x]Value number as a new column called Replicate, but still it isn't in the structure I want as the ID column has redundancies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about something like this using `dplyr`/`purrr`:

```
require(tidyverse);
reduce(lst, full_join, by = "ID");
#   ID Value.x Value.y Value
# 1  A       1       1    NA
# 2  B       1      NA     1
# 3  C       1      NA     1
# 4  D      NA       1    NA
# 5  E      NA       1    NA
```

Or with the `NA`s replaced with `0`s:

```
reduce(lst, full_join, by = "ID") %>% replace(., is.na(.), 0);
#  ID Value.x Value.y Value
#1  A       1       1     0
#2  B       1       0     1
#3  C       1       0     1
#4  D       0       1     0
#5  E       0       1     0
```

---

### Sample data

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
lst <- list(
    data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1, 1)),
    data.frame(ID = c("A", "D", "E"), Value = c(1, 1, 1)),
    data.frame(ID = c("B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1)))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Didn't see the purrr package before. Just one thing extra before I close up. Any way to set the default NA value to, say, 0? Didn't see it on the R documentation page

Comment: No worries @PeptideWitch; I've updated my answer to replace the `NA`s with `0`s.

Comment: You can use `replace(., is.na(.), 0)` instead of `mutate_all(...`

Comment: Very nice. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Cheers @CPak; fixed it.

Comment: Yep, can confirm the suggestion by @CPak - all NAs replaced by 0s.

Comment: `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘reduce’ for signature ‘"list"’` Could someone help with this?

Comment: @Brofessor Make sure you use `purrr`'s `reduce`. If in doubt about namespacing, use `purrr::reduce(lst, full_join, by = "ID")`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a nice answer but the typical way to do this is with `tidyr::spread`

Your data

```
A <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:3], Value=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
B <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[c(1,4,5)], Value=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
C <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[c(2:3)], Value=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
L <- list(A, B, C)
```

Solution

```
dplyr::bind_rows(L, .id="G") %>%
  tidyr::spread(G, Value, fill=0)

  # ID 1 2 3
# 1  A 1 1 0
# 2  B 1 0 1
# 3  C 1 0 1
# 4  D 0 1 0
# 5  E 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer CPak - this solution works really neatly, and has the added advantage of re-naming the column headers. I wish I could tick both answers right...

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`, we need to use `all = TRUE` in the `merge`

```
res <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by="ID"), lst)
replace(res, is.na(res), 0)
#    ID Value.x Value.y Value
#1  A       1       1     0
#2  B       1       0     1
#3  C       1       0     1
#4  D       0       1     0
#5  E       0       1     0
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Value"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
ID = c("A", "D", "E"), Value = c(1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ID", 
 "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
ID = c("B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1)), .Names = c("ID", "Value"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, this throws up the error: Error in merge.data.table: x has some duplicated column name(s): etc etc etc. Please remove or rename the duplicate(s) and try again.

Comment: @PeptideWitch  I added the dataset used.  It is working as expected.  Do you have a `data.table` object?  I am using `data.frame`

Comment: @PeptideWitch  I also checked with data.table object.  It is working fine for me

Comment: Yep, good spotting. I'm actually using a data.table; didn't realise 'fread' was reading my .csv files to a data.table instead of a data.frame. Cheers

Comment: Hmm, wonder why my data.table doesn't like it.

Comment: @PeptideWitch  Please check the version of your data.table.

Comment: data.table_1.10.4-3

Comment: @PeptideWitch  I am using `data.table_1.10.5`