# How do you merge multiple data frames and maintain different column names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I'm looking for a scalable method to multiple data frames together, on this condition that the first column matches, while also maintaining the column names which are different for each dataframe.

In this example there are only three data frames, but I'm working with a couple hundred, so am trying to write code that is scalable.

To provide context, the data files are being read from a folder, and I have a for loop to iterate through the files.

```
files <- list.files(path = "Documents/")

df <- list()

for (i in 1:length(files)) {

   df[[i]] <- read.csv(paste0("Documents/",files[i]))

   # code to perform action goes here

}
```

Below are the sample inputs and the intended output--

This is df[[1]]

```
date    blue
1/1/11  5
1/1/12  6
2/1/13  2
```

This id df[[2]]

```
date    orange
1/1/11  2
1/1/12  5
2/1/13  2
```

This is df[[3]]

```
date    red
1/1/11  4
2/1/13  2
```

This is the intended output:

```
date    blue    orange  red
1/1/11  5       2       4
1/1/12  6       5       NA
2/1/13  2       2       2
```

Comment: you should supply for a reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

The answer is supplied by Matthew Plourde in [Merging a lot of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames)

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use list() in a way so it can take in many dataframes without having to type each one out? (I've edited my question to provide more context)

Comment: of course, the dataframe must have a sequential names though. Like `paste0("jay_df_", 1:1000,".rds")`. Obviiously, if they have all a complete different name you must type one by one..

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`.

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="date    blue
1/1/11  5
1/1/12  6
2/1/13  2")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="date    orange
1/1/11  2
1/1/12  5
2/1/13  2")

df3 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="date    red
1/1/11  4
2/1/13  2")

library(dplyr)
df4 <- full_join(inner_join(df1, df2), df3)

df4
#     date blue orange red
# 1 1/1/11    5      2   4
# 2 1/1/12    6      5  NA
# 3 2/1/13    2      2   2
```

Comment: Even though this question is a duplicate, he is asking for a scalable code to work with many dataframes

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use `Reduce()` and `base::merge()`

```
# data sample organized to a list
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("1/1/11", "1/1/12", "2/1/13"), blue = c(5, 6, 2))
df2 <- data.frame(date = c("1/1/11", "1/1/12", "2/1/13"), orange = c(2, 5, 2))
df3 <- data.frame(date = c("1/1/11", "2/1/13"), red = c(4, 2))
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# solution
merged_df <- Reduce(f = merge, x = df_list)
```