# Paste files while assigning header

Tags: r, unix

I have a list of files that looks like this

FILE10

> ```
> Count_S10        
>   GeneA      0.3      
>   GeneB      0.4
>   GeneC      0.9         
>   GeneD      0.1
> ```

.......................

FILE8

> ```
> Count_S8        
>   GeneA      0.22
>   GeneB      0.76
>   GeneC      0.2         
>   GeneD      0.01
> ```

.......................

FILE13

> ```
> Count_S13        
>   GeneA      0.2      
>   GeneB      0.04
>   GeneC      0.19         
>   GeneD      0.111
> ```

.......................

Totally I have 100 files of 5000 rows. The first column of each file has the header while the second column has not. Moreover in the folder files are not ordered in ascending order. I simply would like the following output:

FILE1

> ```
> Gene_List   Count_S8   Count_S10   Count_S13
>   GeneA      0.22         0.3         0.2
>   GeneB      0.76         0.4         0.04
>   GeneC      0.2          0.9         0.19
>   GeneD      0.01         0.1         0.111
> ```

Here, only Files 8, 10, 13 are shown as an example.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got those example files saved in my "example_files" directory. First, get those files as a list:

```
files <- list.files(path = "example_files", full.names = TRUE)

> files
[1] "example_files/File10.txt" "example_files/File13.txt" "example_files/File8.txt"
```

Get them ordered numerically (as in your expected output):

```
files <- files[order(as.numeric(gsub(".*File|.txt", "", files)))]

> files
[1] "example_files/File8.txt"  "example_files/File10.txt" "example_files/File13.txt"
```

This function takes the first line as the source name, then uses `read.table` to get the actual data, skipping the first line. It then assigns the names correctly for a merge later:

```
read_file <- function(filename) {
  source = readLines(filename)[1]
  df_ = read.table(filename, skip = 1, sep = "")
  names(df_) = c("Gene_List", source)
  return(df_)
}
```

Now, you can call that function over your list of files:

```
list_of_files <- lapply(files, read_file)

> list_of_files
[[1]]
  Gene_List Count_S8
1     GeneA      0.3
2     GeneB      0.4
3     GeneC      0.9
4     GeneD      0.1

[[2]]
  Gene_List Count_S10
1     GeneA      0.22
2     GeneB      0.76
3     GeneC      0.20
4     GeneD      0.01

[[3]]
  Gene_List Count_S13
1     GeneA     0.200
2     GeneB     0.040
3     GeneC     0.190
4     GeneD     0.111
```

Now, use `Reduce` and `merge` to merge the list together (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames)):

```
> Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), list_of_files)
  Gene_List Count_S8 Count_S10 Count_S13
1     GeneA      0.3      0.22     0.200
2     GeneB      0.4      0.76     0.040
3     GeneC      0.9      0.20     0.190
4     GeneD      0.1      0.01     0.111
```