# Merging a list of data.frames with purrr (reduce/reduce2)

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, purrr

This is my data:

```
list_of_data <- list(mtcars[1:26,], mtcars[4:22,], mtcars[3:15,])
```

I want to merge the all dataframes by their rownames.

[Merging a lot of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames)

I know that `Reduce` comes pretty handy for a problem like this, but I am not able to get in inside my `purrr` workflow. Can anyone help me?

I am even not sure if `reduce` or `reduce2` might be suited to get it work. 
This was my try but it does not work:

```
list_of_data %>%
    map(~select(.x, c(cyl, wt))) %>%
    reduce2(~merge(.x, .y,  all=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what's your intent:

```r
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

list_of_data %>% 
  map(~select(.x, cyl, wt)) %>% 
  map(rownames_to_column) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "rowname")
```

We can use `dplyr::full_join` with `purrr::reduce` to merge multiple dataframes. But to be able to merge by rownames, first we need to write them to a column. `tibble::rownames_to_column` does that. By default the column is called "rowname".