# How to merge a list of file that are in the environment following a mapping file

Tags: r, merge, rule-engine

I have a list of file in my R environment. I want to merge some of them together using a mapping file.

The mapping file is named map_rule1, and it looks like following.

```
map_rule1
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  EDC_file_name Tab             DatasetName         GroupVar1
  <chr>         <chr>           <chr>               <chr>    
1 e1            Demographics    Demographics Merged Subject  
2 e2            Demographics    NA                  NA       
3 e3            PatientRegister Patient Register    Subject  
4 e4            PatientRegister NA                  NA       
5 e5            PatientRegister NA                  NA       
6 e6            PatientRegister NA                  NA       
7 e7            PatientConsent  Patient Consent     NA       
8 e8            PatientConsent  NA                  NA
```

The items listed in Data col are the files that are in my current r environment. I want to merge the ones that are categorized as the same domain into one file by the variable that listed in Group_V1, and the new data name that listed in New_data_Name. I have 100+ file that need to be merged. that is why I want to create an looping method or any other way to merge those file automatically.

sample data and Map_Rule can be build by using codes:

```
e1<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), SEX = structure(c(2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L))


e2<-
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), RACE = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Black (including African, Caribbean descent)", 
 "Caucasian"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L)) 
e3<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), ETHNIC_STD = c(2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L)) 


e4<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), subjectId = c(168L, 
 171L, 174L, 175L, 196L, 199L, 207L, 208L, 213L, 209L, 210L, 212L, 
 283L, 325L, 329L, 527L, 315L, 316L, 320L, 334L, 339L, 582L, 319L, 
 523L, 526L, 601L, 532L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L))

e5<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), siteid = c(9L, 9L, 
 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L))
e5<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), siteid = c(9L, 9L, 
 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L))

e7<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0007", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Urban", "Ural"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L))
e8<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
 7L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 20L, 16L), .Label = c("300-0001", 
 "300-0002", "300-0003", "300-0004", "300-0005", "300-0006", "300-0007", 
 "300-0008", "300-0009", "301-0001", "301-0002", "301-0003", "301-0004", 
 "301-0005", "301-0006", "302-0001", "303-0001", "303-0002", "303-0003", 
 "303-0004", "304-0001", "304-0002", "304-0003", "304-0004", "304-0005", 
 "304-0006", "304-0007"), class = "factor"), SEX = structure(c(2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -27L))

map_rule1<-structure(list(EDC_file_name = c("e1", "e2", "e3", 
 "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8"), Tab = c("Demographics", 
 "Demographics", "PatientRegister", "PatientRegister", "PatientRegister", 
 "PatientRegister", "PatientConsent", "PatientConsent"), DatasetName = c("Demographics Merged", 
 NA, "Patient Register", NA, NA,  NA, "Patient Consent", NA), GroupVar1 = c( "Subject", 
  NA, "Subject",  NA, NA,  NA, 
  NA,  NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any advice on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: You should 1) post the output from `dput(head(Map_Rule))`, sincedata via  pictures imply that you think it's our responsibility to create a test suite for this project, and 2 explain what is to be done with file that have NA as their Group_V1 value . (I'm not averse to spending time with this, since I have a project that requires something very much like it that I've been considering bringing up to speed.)

Comment: hello, I have updated the post with code to build Map_Rule. and each domain only need one variable to merge. the first record of Group_V1 for each domain is the variable that use for merge; if the first record of Group_V1 is "NA", then we should append the data instead of merge them. Hope these explain the idea.

Comment: Can you try `i1 <- map_rule1$EDC_file_name %in% ls(); split(mget(map_rule1$EDC_file_name[i1]), map_rule1$Tab[i1]) %>% map2(na.omit(map_rule1$GroupVar1), ~ reduce(.x, inner_join, by = .y))`

Comment: I used `library(dplyr);library(purrr)`

Comment: I got following error message "Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 3
* `.y` has length 2"

Comment: I was thinking maybe I can split data for merge and append, and then process them separately. If we can do merge/append all together in one pass, it is even better. Still trying. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think might work.  Tested on a sanitized version of the `map_rule1` set of rules: It had two sources of error that you probably will need to trap or pre-sanitize against: 1) `e6` was undefined, and 2) I decided that figuring out how to deal with the missing merge-`by` columns was an additional level of complexity that I didn't feel up to:

```
 temp  <- lapply( split(map_rule1, map_rule1$Tab) , 
             # breaks into groups by Domain
                   function( d){ assign( d$DatasetName[1], 
                                        # names= first items in col
                   # I don't generally use assign but seems reasonable here
                     Reduce( function(x,y){ merge(x,y, by=d$GroupVar1[1])}, 
                                              lapply(d$EDC_file_name, get) ) ,
                                            #use first item as named by-argument 
                                 envir=globalenv() )}
             # named objects need to  appear outside this function
                )
#need to run this before calculating `temp`
map_rule1 <- 
structure(list(EDC_file_name = c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5"
), Tab = c("Demographics", "Demographics", "PatientRegister", 
"PatientRegister", "PatientRegister"), DatasetName = c("Demographics Merged", 
NA, "Patient Register", NA, NA), GroupVar1 = c("Subject", NA, 
"Subject", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

-----------results-------

```
# First what was in temp
str(temp)
List of 2
 $ Demographics   :'data.frame':    27 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Subject: Factor w/ 27 levels "300-0001","300-0002",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ SEX    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ RACE   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Black (including African, Caribbean descent)",..: 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ PatientRegister:'data.frame':    27 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Subject   : Factor w/ 27 levels "300-0001","300-0002",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ ETHNIC_STD: int [1:27] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ subjectId : int [1:27] 168 171 174 199 175 196 207 208 213 315 ...
  ..$ siteid    : int [1:27] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 15 ...
```

---

```
 # Second the results in the global environment 
 # with the weird un-Rish names containing spaces

 `Demographics Merged`
    Subject    SEX                                         RACE
1  300-0001   Male                                    Caucasian
2  300-0002 Female                                    Caucasian
3  300-0003   Male                                    Caucasian
4  300-0004 Female                                    Caucasian
5  300-0005   Male                                    Caucasian
6  300-0006 Female Black (including African, Caribbean descent)
7  300-0007   Male                                    Caucasian
8  300-0008   Male                                    Caucasian
9  300-0009   Male                                    Caucasian
10 301-0001   Male                                    Caucasian
11 301-0002 Female                                    Caucasian
12 301-0003   Male                                    Caucasian
13 301-0004   Male                                    Caucasian
14 301-0005   Male Black (including African, Caribbean descent)
15 301-0006   Male                                    Caucasian
16 302-0001   Male                                    Caucasian
17 303-0001   Male                                    Caucasian
18 303-0002   Male Black (including African, Caribbean descent)
19 303-0003   Male                                    Caucasian
20 303-0004   Male                                    Caucasian
21 304-0001   Male                                    Caucasian
22 304-0002   Male                                    Caucasian
23 304-0003 Female Black (including African, Caribbean descent)
24 304-0004   Male Black (including African, Caribbean descent)
25 304-0005   Male Black (including African, Caribbean descent)
26 304-0006 Female                                    Caucasian
27 304-0007   Male                                    Caucasian
```

You could get  unRish-named-results in your workspace just by running the `lapply` code without assigning its results to `temp`.

Comment: Could you explain more on `do.call( merge, append( lapply(d$Data, read.csv) ,
list( by=d$Group_V1[1]) ), envir=global.env() `? why we need `read.csv`? the data has been imported and just has name .csv. how do we chose to do merge or append automatically?

Comment: I think merge can not be used for more than 2 data frame. so maybe `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=c("d$GroupV1[1]","d$GroupV2[1]"), list(d$Data) `need to be used. but i am not sure how to put a list of data for the subset and whether we could run a function inside of a function. maybe sth like case_when to define use merge or append if` is.na(d$GroupV1[1]`. These are all I can think. Helps really needed in order to get a runable codes

Comment: Need read csv if the files are still on disk with those names. Unless you named your R objects that (confusing) way???  May need to use a `Reduce` call for more than 2 files at a time. But you should  not need to us both d$GroupV1[1]","d$GroupV2[1] at least with the data structure you provided so far. If teh merge columns have the same name you do not need to repeat. If you would follow through on making a test suite, I'm still open to further efforts, but not with the current situation.

Comment: There's also a `merge_all` function in the reshape package. And there's an example of a `Reduce` wrapper around `merge` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096814/merging-a-lot-of-data-frames/14096854#14096854

Comment: Sorry, my data do have .CVS as name as use codes to read mass .CSV files into R. I put d$GroupV2[1] in is because my real data might need to be merge by two variables.

Comment: I think you have all the pieces. You should either respond substantively to the request to post test objects for the "csv" entities whatever their form or mark this as answered.

Comment: The codes that you suggested did not work for some reason. I have updated my post with sample data. based on the file, e7and e8 need to be append together as groupV1[1]=NA

Comment: If you run `lists.d <- lapply(map_rule1$EDC_file_name, get)` you find that `e6` is missing from the action. I just removed it since having it would serve little purpose. However you will probably need to run an error check with `try()` or `all(exists())`.

Comment: Thanks for working on this project. I am working on append one. I am new to R so might take some time. Will keep you updated if I make any progress. :) Thanks again.