# how to build a variable base on another col 's summary

Tags: r, split

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

you can get sample data using code:

```
df <- structure(list(Var = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", 
"v8", "v9", "v10"), Domain = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
"Group4", "Group4", "Group4", "Group2", "Group2", "Group3", "Group3"
), Groupvar = c("v1", NA, NA, "v5", NA, NA, NA, NA, "v10", NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like to build a new variable "Action" to define the action I want to do further using the rule: If there is a !is.na groupvar within same domian, the action=="Merge", if no !is.na groupvar for that domain, then Action=="Append". The dinal data should looks like this:

[image]

what should I do? I think I should use `lapply( split(df, df$Domain) , ...`, I am new to R and still get confused with list and data.Frame. Not sure what I should do after I split the data by domain. What I want to do is sth like egen. Any guidance on what I should do in order to build variable "Action" will be high appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to do a group by 'Domain' and create the 'Action' with `if/else` i.e. `if` `all` the values in 'Groupvar' are `NA` then return 'Append' or `else` 'Merge'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Domain) %>%
    mutate(Action = if(all(is.na(Groupvar))) 'Append' else 'Merge') %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Var   Domain Groupvar Action
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr> 
# 1 v1    Group1 v1       Merge 
# 2 v2    Group1 <NA>     Merge 
# 3 v3    Group1 <NA>     Merge 
# 4 v4    Group4 v5       Merge 
# 5 v5    Group4 <NA>     Merge 
# 6 v6    Group4 <NA>     Merge 
# 7 v7    Group2 <NA>     Append
# 8 v8    Group2 <NA>     Append
# 9 v9    Group3 v10      Merge 
#10 v10   Group3 <NA>     Merge
```

---

Or can also be written as

```
df %>%
     mutate(Action = c("Append", "Merge")[1 + 
             (Domain %in% Domain[complete.cases(Groupvar)])])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Var   Domain Groupvar Action
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr> 
# 1 v1    Group1 v1       Merge 
# 2 v2    Group1 <NA>     Merge 
# 3 v3    Group1 <NA>     Merge 
# 4 v4    Group4 v5       Merge 
# 5 v5    Group4 <NA>     Merge 
# 6 v6    Group4 <NA>     Merge 
# 7 v7    Group2 <NA>     Append
# 8 v8    Group2 <NA>     Append
# 9 v9    Group3 v10      Merge 
#10 v10   Group3 <NA>     Merge
```

---

If we want to use `split`, then an option is

```
df$Action <- unsplit(lapply(split(df$Groupvar, df$Domain), 
function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) rep('Append', length(x)) else
      rep('Merge', length(x))), df$Domain)
df$Action
#[1] "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Append" "Append" "Merge"  "Merge"
```

---

Or a more compact option in `base R` is

```
c("Append", "Merge")[1 + (df$Domain %in% na.omit(df)$Domain)]
#[1] "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Merge"  "Append" "Append" "Merge"  "Merge"
```

Comment: You are right. I work too much with split these days and forget about `group_by`. Thanks so much for the prompt reply. :)

Comment: @Stataq Thanks.  I updated with `split`.  Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks so much!  It did not allowed me to accept answer within 12 mins. I now accepted. we are working on a project to speed up merge/append process. I just fixed the sample e6. Could you give me some idea on that? The post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914448/how-to-merge-a-list-of-file-that-are-in-the-environment-following-a-mapping-file. If it is not doable, i am fully understand. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this option. The function `ifelse()` is vectorized and can wrap any other function as logical tests in order to avoid the addition of functions that work at other levels:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% group_by(Domain) %>%
  mutate(Action=ifelse(sum(!is.na(Groupvar))>=1,'Merge','Append'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Domain [4]
   Var   Domain Groupvar Action
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr> 
 1 v1    Group1 v1       Merge 
 2 v2    Group1 NA       Merge 
 3 v3    Group1 NA       Merge 
 4 v4    Group4 v5       Merge 
 5 v5    Group4 NA       Merge 
 6 v6    Group4 NA       Merge 
 7 v7    Group2 NA       Append
 8 v8    Group2 NA       Append
 9 v9    Group3 v10      Merge 
10 v10   Group3 NA       Merge
```

Comment: Never know that we can do `sum(!is.na(Groupvar))>=1`. This one is more like rsum and egen in stata. :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to split the data you can do this in base R with `ave` :

```
df$Action <- with(df, ifelse(ave(!is.na(Groupvar), Domain, FUN = any), 
                      'Merge', 'Append'))
df

# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Var   Domain Groupvar Action
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr> 
# 1 v1    Group1 v1       Merge 
# 2 v2    Group1 NA       Merge 
# 3 v3    Group1 NA       Merge 
# 4 v4    Group4 v5       Merge 
# 5 v5    Group4 NA       Merge 
# 6 v6    Group4 NA       Merge 
# 7 v7    Group2 NA       Append
# 8 v8    Group2 NA       Append
# 9 v9    Group3 v10      Merge 
#10 v10   Group3 NA       Merge
```